# Android Studio XML error "Corresponding method handler not found" on onClick

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, kotlin

Why do I get error "Corresponding method handler not found" on the XML onClick line, after naming the onClick in XML and calling it on Main Activity?

Snippet from activity_main.xml:

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buPercentage"
            android:layout_width="30pt"
            android:layout_height="30pt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/lightgray"
            android:onClick="buPercentageEvent" //Error says Corresponding method handler not found
            android:text="%"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Snippet from MainActivity.kt

```
fun buPercentageEvent()
{
    val convertToDecimal = displayText.text.toString()
    val newNumber = convertToDecimal.toDouble() / 100
    displayText.setText(newNumber.toString())
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
fun test(view: View){
        Log.e("Click","Yes")
    }
```

This will work.

Comment: Thank you very much! Mind giving a brief explanation?

Comment: There is nothing to explain, you got to pass the view in param, accept the answer if this worked.

Comment: @Sinistro click on the right icon below the up/down icon of the answer, if it is workable for u

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha didn't understand?

Comment: What? ..I just said to questioner that accept the answer if it is workable for u

Comment: Another discussion about the same problem, still not solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610193/cannot-find-onclick-method-in-activity-from-xml-definition