# Cannot find onClick method in activity from xml definition

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I am trying to link a function to the onClick property of a button in AndroidStudio but for some reason the system cannot identify the method that I coded.

The funny thing is that it works correctly when I code it in Java. In Kotlin it does not. I updated my Kotlin and checked its configuration but I cannot find the problem. My friend tried the same thing I did in a Linux computer and it worked for him. I have a Mac OS, I don't know if there is some extra configuration to take care of. Can anyone help me?

This is my simple activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun sendMessage(view: View) {

    }
}
```

This is the xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:text="@string/send_button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

In build.gradle I have:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Error message:

```
Corresponding method handler 'public void sendMessage(android.view.View)' not found

The onClick attribute value should be the name of a method in this View's context to invoke when the view is clicked.

This name must correspond to a public method that takes exactly one parameter of type View.  Must be a string value, using '\;' to escape characters such as '\n' or '\uxxxx' for a unicode character
```

Comment: We have a lot of way.please check https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-frameworks.html

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the actual error text?

Comment: It is there. The funny thing is that the error message complains about "public void sendMessage(android.view.View)" which is Java. But the whole code is in Kotlin

Comment: Try adding the tools:context to the root node of your xml, and see if it works? Else you can suppress the lint error for now and move ahead.

Comment: try using open fun sendMessage()

Comment: I am having the same problem, I think it is because the byte code when converted to java has this signature: 
public final void onClickButton(@Nullable android.view.View view)

I think the expected signature wold be:
'public void onClickButton(android.view.View)

But if it is the problem, I don't know how to solve =(

Comment: If I "open" the class: 
"open class TestActivity" and the method:  "open fun onClickButton(view: View?) ", the Notation Nullable or NotNull still persists... I will turn off the abortOnError lint for while:   "android { lintOptions { 
 abortOnError false } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now. I had to restart AndroidStudio. I still cannot add the function using the attributes window in the design tab but it works if I edit the XML directly.

Comment: what does that mean if I edit the xml directly! I have same problem as your question so whats the correct answer or method to do ?

Comment: As far as I remember, I added 'android:onClick="sendMessage"' to the XML and restarted AndroidStudio. It worked at the time. I am sorry I cannot help you more, I haven't worked with this in a while.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
tools:context="com.somepackage.MainActivity"
```

to your top view in xml

Comment: Are you sure it's correct? Because without it there is a warning

Comment: Yes, I am. I think there was a conflict with Kotlin and Java when I converted the code. Maybe there was some misconfiguration. I restarted AndroidStudio and now it works.